# OpenStack Ansible

Tags: ansible, authorization, openstack, keystone

Trying to deploy OpenStack using Ansible https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/openstack-ansible

When launching the "setup-openstack.yml" playbook, the following error appears:

> FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: os_glance : Ensure glance service (1 retries left).
>   fatal: [infra1_glance_container-0674dd3b]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 5, "changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ARIvJ_/ansible_module_keystone.py\", line 1458, in \n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ARIvJ_/ansible_module_keystone.py\", line 1452, in main\n    km.command_router()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ARIvJ_/ansible_module_keystone.py\", line 484, in command_router\n    facts = action(variables=action_command['variables'])\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ARIvJ_/ansible_module_keystone.py\", line 1029, in ensure_service\n    self._authenticate()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ARIvJ_/ansible_module_keystone.py\", line 606, in _authenticate\n    self.keystone = client.Client(**client_args)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/v3/client.py\", line 238, in **init**\n    self.authenticate()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/positional/**init**.py\", line 101, in inner\n    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/httpclient.py\", line 581, in authenticate\n    resp = self.get_raw_token_from_identity_service(**kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/v3/client.py\", line 324, in get_raw_token_from_identity_service\n    _('Authorization failed: %s') % e)\nkeystoneauth1.exceptions.auth.AuthorizationFailure: Authorization failed: Unable to establish connection to http://192.168.56.11:35357/v3/auth/tokens\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}

It is probably related to Keystone! 192.168.56.11 is the IP address of the deployment host. The output of "curl http://192.168.56.11:35357/v3" is the following:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

While "curl 192.168.56.79:35357/v3" (Keystone LXC container) gives:

> {"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2017-02-22T00:00:00Z", "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v3+json"}], "id": "v3.8", "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.56.79:35357/v3/", "rel": "self"}]}}

Any insights about how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a token problem (glance trying to get a token from keystone). For experimental (ONLY) deployments, disable SSL to avoid this error (otherwise, get a valide certificates).
The problem is solved by adding "**haproxy_ssl: false**" to "**/etc/openstack_deploy/user_variables.yml**" and running the "**haproxy-install.yml**" playbook to take the modifications into account. Then run your "setup-openstack.yml" playbook!